# A circularly charged insulating disk rotates

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

A circularly charged insulating disk rotates around its axis. Why is there a magnetic field around the rotating disc?

Comment: Do you mean a charged insulating disk?

Comment: Yeah sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving charges constitute a current density, which creates a magnetic field by the Biot-Savart Law,

$$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\iiint\frac{\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r}’)\times(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}’)}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}’|^3}d^3\mathbf{r}’.$$

This is the magnetostatic analog of Coulomb’s Law in electrostatics, which gives the electric field created by a charge density,

$$\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\iiint\frac{\rho(\mathbf{r}’)(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}’)}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}’|^3}d^3\mathbf{r}’.$$

These laws hold when the charge density and current density don’t change with time, which is the case for a rotating disk. The disk rotates, and the charges on the disk rotate along with it, but the charge density and current density are unchanging.